# Multiple Aggregate Case Expression Performance

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

We have a bit of a monster view in our database that does some condition aggregation on a wide view with about 900 million rows.  Do do conditional aggregation it uses multiple case expressions.  I've optimized the indexes as best I can and the view that this view is based on returns the data relatively quickly.  However once it tries to do all these aggregates at once performance drops condsiderably.  The code for the view can be found [here](https://zerobin.net/?d95ec4693a8857f2#GcObZZSna/AGXvJFD7kiAwiPvcUgGny6fhkVTybwC1Y=) in case you want to see it though I'm not sure for my question it's necessary.

I've taken a random selection of 10K contacts and inserted into a table and did an INNER JOIN on the ContactID of the table and view selecting all aggregate columns.  This takes about 30 minutes to return the results.  The estimated plan of the query can be found [here](https://zerobin.net/?6d43f251f856f46f#rnEc3wE5XTXR2DFkY6rtaFlI+x3QveZNaT5e34QJFRc=).

When I create a select for each aggregate in the view and run them one by one as below I get the results in about 5 minutes.

```
SELECT  [TDV].[ContactID],
        [TDV].[Dog_FoodTx12mth]
FROM    [Dimension].[Transactions_DataView] [TDV]
    INNER JOIN [Dimension].[Contacts]
        ON     [Contacts].[ContactID] = [TDV].[ContactID];
GO
SELECT  [TDV].[ContactID],
        [TDV].[Cat_FoodTx12mth]
FROM    [Dimension].[Transactions_DataView] [TDV]
    INNER JOIN [Dimension].[Contacts]
        ON     [Contacts].[ContactID] = [TDV].[ContactID];
--repeat the pattern above for each individual aggregate
```

This doesn't make much sense to me as the query will need to pull the data from the underlying tables each time it runs anyway, I would have thought doing 1 pull of the data and then aggregating it all would be quicker.

Does anyone have a good idea of why this is the case?

Edit:

Thanks for all your replies.

The question can be boiled down to why does using multiple DISTINCT Aggregate have such a negative impact on performance?

Comment: Could add the table structure, too and the indexes?

Comment: Having looked at the full query I would say your main problem is having so many `count distinct` operations.  You ***really*** need to simplify that query.

Comment: @gotqn
The view GI_TransactionLineProductContact is built off of several tables and an indexed view I could potentially post the table structures and indexes but I'm not sure how helpful it will be as I can return the data unaggregated from them for 10000 contacts in about 30 seconds.  It isn't until I start doing multiple aggregations using CASE expressions that things start really slowing down.  So it doesn't seem that it's having a problem getting to the underlying data.

Comment: @iamdave
I can look at simplifying the query but I'm really trying to understand why if I do all those count distincts as separate queries that need to pull the data over and over why it runs quicker than doing them all at once with 1 retrieval of the underlying data.

Comment: Because the `count distinct` is a horrendously inefficient operator.  The problem almost certainly isn't that you are doing `case` expressions.  Try to find a more efficient way to aggregate your data.

Comment: Have you tried not using nested views? That is a sure fire way to totally confuse the optimizer. Nested views seem so logical but they are the work of the devil. https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/performance/the-seven-sins-against-tsql-performance/#seven

Comment: @SeanLange Thanks for the link and suggestion.  I'll keep that in mind for the future.  In this case I removed the nested views on got the same execution plan.

Comment: @Bee_Riii Please post your table schemas, post a few rows of imagined example data, describe what the query is supposed to achieve and post the expected result in table form. Please leave out any unimportant columns. Example table data could be as few as 10 lines (per table involved). Then we can discuss the table schemas and queries ;)

Comment: Can you post the plan here? https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/ This is a pretty big ask going on. That query is over 1700 lines long and there are tons of scans happening due to the leading wildcards in many of your LIKE predicates.

Comment: If a query is 1700 lines long, then the data is not stored in a way which makes the query easy to write. In other words, the data format is wrong. Which is the reason i wanted to discuss table schemas. Also, how do we put this into stackoverflow chat?

Comment: @SeanLange it's too large I've posted it as text above and you can download the plan from http://www.filedropper.com/fullquery

Comment: Oh and for this big a query: also add the indexes, please.

Comment: @Bee_Riii Because it's so large, please reduce the problem to a small example which we can solve. Basically, abstract what the same repeating parts to just one part. If you have 100 count's then add just one select count. Maybe two, if it's involved in joins. Minimal reproducible complete examples please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this [MSDN article](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqlqueryprocessing/2008/09/22/distinct-aggregation-considered-harmful/) that explains the cause.

Quote from the article:
"SQL Server 2008 does not compute these distinct aggregates “along the way.”  Mixing one or more distinct aggregates with non-distinct aggregates in the same select list, or mixing two or more distinct aggregates, leads to spooling and rereading of intermediate results – which can be more expensive than computing the distinct aggregates in a separate query!  In the worst case, such as the fragment of code above, this is sort of inevitable.  The SQL Server 2008 query processor cannot compute aggregates on a stream without destroying the stream.  So computing the distinct aggregate consumes the stream, which has to be recomputed for the other aggregates."

Hopefully this will help someone in the future.

Thanks @iamdave for pointing me in the right direction to research.